Manage Volenteer Projects gives error
I'm using wordpress 6.6.1, civicrm 5.76.2, CiviVolunteer 2.4.5, and angular profiles 6.2.4.  Manage Volumteers gives the following error
Unable to load template 'file:CRM/Volunteer/Page/Angular.tpl' in 'file:CRM/common/CMSPrint.tpl
most of the Volunteer menu options give the same error.  I've migrated the database from a drupal 7 site that does not have this error.  I've tried removing and installing the extension but it has the same error. could there be something in the old data causing it? everything else seems to work. I did the path updates and all as the migration doc said to.
CRM/common/CMSPrint.tpl is wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/common/CMSPrint.tpl  and CRM/Volunteer/Page/Angular.tpl is wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/templates/CRM/Volunteer/Page/Angular.tpl
I'm guessing something is off with the template include paths, how do I verify it's right? the paths all exist, owned by www-data and all read permissions.
debug:
SmartyException: "Unable to load template 'file:CRM/Volunteer/Page/Angular.tpl' in 'file:CRM/common/CMSPrint.tpl'"

#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(386): Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/bc/19/6e/bc196e41357dc2444b0537605167c8977d6b1254_0.file.CMSPrint.tpl.php(103): Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender("CRM/Volunteer/Page/Angular.tpl", NULL, NULL, 0, 3600, (Array:0), 0, TRUE)
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php(123): content_66d4b63f207f64_04542824(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php(114): Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(217): Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#5 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(386): Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
#6 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/3f/51/03/3f5103ae173fa138b80a229d6310ac4f36230d43_0.file.wordpress.tpl.php(31): Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender("file:CRM/common/CMSPrint.tpl", NULL, NULL, 0, 3600, (Array:0), 0, FALSE)
#7 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php(123): content_66d4b63f1f03e3_26711702(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#8 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php(114): Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#9 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(217): Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#10 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(238): Smarty_Internal_Template->render(FALSE, 0)
#11 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(116): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template), NULL, NULL, NULL, 0)
#12 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page.php(273): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch("CRM/common/wordpress.tpl")
#13 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Page/Angular.php(10): CRM_Core_Page->run()
#14 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(333): CRM_Volunteer_Page_Angular->run((Array:3), NULL)
#15 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:17))
#16 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#17 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1231): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#18 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#19 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#20 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#21 /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#22 {main}


PHP version? Memory? Does the extension have any issues with the empty bracket syndrome?

php 8.2.22, free reports 140mb free and minimal swap

What is empty bracket syndrome?  google doesn't have any relevant hits on that

Was a term we used to use for the PHP version changes from 7.x to 8.x as it left empty brackets in some of the non-updated extensions.

the working site is on php 8.1.28, so it seems that's not it

Sorry, have been dealing with illness in the family. What I was driving at is that in WordPress, at least, when I bumped up the PHP to 8.x a lot of the Extensions had { } that had empty character(s). It could be as simple as an Extension issue. With that said, I am not familiar with the Drupal conversion and hopefully someone will chime in with far more knowledge on the matter. I would also list the WordPress version as that helps the smarter than I folks know how it all interplays. I wish you the best!
